How is Alternate Data Streams used to block DLLs from executing on Windows?
We ran into a situation this week where our Unit Test CI/CD step started to fail on one of our build servers, but not on others.
After investigating, we concluded that the issue was due to a security block from Windows on the C# test adapter DLL file. When inspecting the file on the offending build server, we see this:

The file has been marked as "unsafe", apparently using the Alternate Data Stream (ADS) feature.
I've tried searching a bit more on how this works but couldn't find an answer that justifies why this particular file got blocked on one of our machines but not on others.
What exactly drives this security lock? This particular file is part of a NuGet package that is downloaded during our CI/CD process as part of the "package restore" step. This is the standard way to manage dependencies in .NET applications.
I've heard that ADS kicks in when for example, a person downloads a file from the browser, but why is it affecting a DLL file that is downloaded by a background build process like this, and why would it not affect the same DLL uniformly across all of our build servers the same way?
We're trying to understand this a bit better before taking any drastic action, such as attempting to just turn the whole "capability" off (if that's even possible).

SmartScreen is one part of the file is blocked or unblocked.

Whatever source you are copying the file(s) from, add its hostname, IP, or domain to the Local intranet (or Trusted sites) list security zones on your target system(s).  By default, your Windows OS is probably placing the source site in the Internet security zone, resulting in untrusted target files when they are written onto your system.
